# Forking in linux

Tags: c, linux, exec, fork

I'm having some issues understanding `fork()` in linux.

What is confusing me is if a parent forks a child process and that child calls `execl()` and

`execl()` doesn't return and the parent process waits on the child to exit, will the system then

hang?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here's a code example from mdadm.  So in the child process after `execl()` there is `exit(1)`.
If `execl()` doesn't return then will `exit(0)` ever execute?  If not then the parent will wait  indefinitely? Am I right here?

```
if (!check_env("MDADM_NO_SYSTEMCTL"))
    switch(fork()) {
    case 0:
        /* FIXME yuk. CLOSE_EXEC?? */
        skipped = 0;
        for (i = 3; skipped < 20; i++)
            if (close(i) < 0)
                skipped++;
            else
                skipped = 0;

        /* Don't want to see error messages from
         * systemctl.  If the service doesn't exist,
         * we start mdmon ourselves.
         */
        close(2);
        open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
        snprintf(pathbuf, sizeof(pathbuf), "mdmon@%s.service",
             devnm);
        status = execl("/usr/bin/systemctl", "systemctl",
                   "start",
                   pathbuf, NULL);
        status = execl("/bin/systemctl", "systemctl", "start",
                   pathbuf, NULL);
        exit(1);
    case -1: pr_err("cannot run mdmon. "
            "Array remains readonly\n");
        return -1;
    default: /* parent - good */
        pid = wait(&status);
        if (pid >= 0 && status == 0)
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a piece of codes to illustrate the scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that `execl` never returns (except if there is an error, which means `execl` failed, i.e. it did "nothing" -- the child process still executes in the same module).

If the parent process waits for a child process to exit, then it will obviously block doing so. That is however expected behavior and it is not the same as "the system hangs". The system *does not* hang.

**EDIT:**
Concerning the code posted in the edited question: First, an [almost] exact duplicate of the process is created using `fork`. Actually, one doesn't care about creating a duplicate, but one really wants to create a *new* process. However, under Unix, new processes are *forked*, not *created* from scratch.
Then follow two calls to `execl`. Normally, the first one should already never return. Instead, the executable `systemctl` will be loaded to replace the child process, and the child process will continue running from the entry point of `systemctl` (this is a very simplified description, but it's essentially that).
Thus `systemctl` will run, as a "new" independent process (in reality, it "stole" the forked process!), and it will (hopefully) eventually exit, which causes the parent process to return from `wait`.

It may however happen that `systemctl` cannot be found in `/usr/bin` (or some other error occurs). For that case, the programmer of the above code makes another attempt at loading `systemctl` from `/bin`. Again, if this works, `execl` will not return, but the code in `systemctl` will execute and eventually exit. The parent process will then unblock from `wait`.

Lastly, if that second call to `execl` *also* fails (i.e. returns), the author gives up and simply calls `exit(1)`, which returns a non-zero "error" code to the parent waking from `wait`.

Comment: I'd clarify that `execl()` replaces the child process in place, i.e. the parent is now waiting for the new process to exit.

Comment: @Hasturkun: If `execl` succeeded, yes. Otherwise it waits on the child process which is [almost] identical to itself. But the parent has no way of knowing that (not without some form of IPC anyway). An error, if any, is returned to the child (who called `execl`), not the parent. The parent merely waits on the process _exiting_, it does not know or care whether the process image was replaced. Unrelated to that, one should note that the parent really _needs_ to wait in any case too (though possibly from the `SIGCHLD` handler with `WNOHANG`, or some similar construct) to reap zombies.

Comment: True. I was just under the impression that the question asker assumed that since `execl()` doesn't return, the forked child will never exit.

Answer (score 2):

If `exec` doesn't return, that means that the process is executing some (new) code. The new code fully replace the old one, so returning from a successful `exec` is nonsense as the call to `exec` is in the old code.

During this time the parent process is `wait`ing the end of its child's execution. So the parent will be blocked until the child terminates.

Answer (score 1):

If a process is waiting on another process, and that other process calls exec(), the process that gets exec'd is now the process the first process is waiting for. So the system won't hang, and the first process will continue executing if/when the exec'd process exits.

Answer (score 0):

No. Every process is started using a fork() call and then the child doing a call from exec() family {see man for execl, execlp, execle, execv, execvp, execvpe}. The first process launched after boot is "init" and all processes can be traced back to "init" using their "ppid".